# How do I verify if I need to rebuild a project programatically

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have an add-in that does operations to open projects in the current solution. Before I do any of those operation, I want to verify if I need to build the projects or now. Is there a way I can check if a project is out of date (Up-To-Date = True)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate in the project list and check

```
Project.Saved
```

property. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.project.saved(VS.80).aspx)

Your friend is the *ENVDTE* namespace, the

> (..) assembly-wrapped COM library containing the objects and members for Visual Studio core automation. Library content is unchanged from prior versions of Visual Studio. All changes and new functionality are contained in EnvDTE80.